# Adding PCL project to VSIX not working

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, vsix

I´m trying to create a **multi-project-solution-template** with VSIX for my Xamarin solutions but I just **can´t get the template to work when I add a PCL** to it.

I´m using [this Git project](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/multiprojtemplatedemo) (see [How to create a multi project template](https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-a-multi-project-template)) as a boiler plate and I can easily add ordinary projects (e.g class libraries) to it and get them to work just fine.

I´m ***guessing*** it is not working because **I probably need to add some Dependencies in the vsixmanifest file** to e.g  ASP.NET Core 1.0 or more of the stuff the PCL is referring to.

*But I have not been able to find out what to add to get it to work..* and of course this could be something totally different...

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a current limitation compared to the roadmap: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/

Comment: Thank you! I posted a comment on the link you provided to get a concete answer but no one has answered. Can you tell my why you think this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to change the PCL to the new **.net Standard** by using this guide [".NET Standard Library with Xamarin Forms"](https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/) and it **works like a charm**. But with Xamarin.Forms 2.3.1.114 I needed to go for netstandard 1.**4**.

So my project.json file looks like this

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
  "Xamarin.Forms": "2.3.1.114",
  "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
  "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1"
},
 "frameworks": {
   "netstandard1.4": {
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8"
      ]
   }
 }
}
```

This [".NET Standard with Xamarin Forms Gotchas"](https://xamarinhelp.com/net-standard-xamarin-forms-gotchas/) might also help you as it did me.